# List Feature Classes print blank

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, feature-class, list

I will write a script that must iterate through the subfolders in the PPA folder, and to iterate through the subfolders, I need to reset and list workspaces (there are two folders under PPA named TT20_3Min, TT20_5Min), and then I need to list polygon by listing feature class.
I can list workspaces; my workspaces are being printed. But feature classes print blank.

```
import arcpy as ap
# Setting workspace

ap.env.workspace = "C:/Student/PPA"

# Existence Check
if ap.Exists("PPA.gdb"):
    ap.management.Delete("PPA.gdb")
    ap.CreateFileGDB_management("C:/Student/PPA", "PPA.gdb")
else:
    ap.CreateFileGDB_management("C:/Student/PPA", "PPA.gdb")

# Listing Workspace
workspaces = ap.ListWorkspaces("*", "Folder")
print(workspaces)

# Listing Feature Class
for wp in workspaces:
    fc = ap.ListFeatureClasses("*")
    print(fc)
```

Comment: You are listing feature classes in current workspace, which is always `ap.env.workspace = "C:/Student/PPA"`, you need to set `ap.env.workspace` for each iteration to point at the different folders or geodatabases

Comment: I suggest using [Walk - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/walk.htm) instead of the older/legacy listing functions.